# AWS API Gateway Service Orchestration

Tags: amazon-web-services, orchestration

Is there any way to orchestrate the micro services from API gateway? I have two micro servicess  and I am tring to aggregate the data from the API gateway. Tried with STEP function but it is asynchronized in nature.

Request will come to the API gateway, we need to call multiple services and aggregate the data and send it back

Answer (score 0):

You can try lambda function to aggregate different services response.

[image: aws lambda aggregation]